# How to make the first 2 characters of a string uppercase?

Tags: php, string

How can I use the PHP strtoupper function for the first two characters of a string? Or is there another function for that?

So the string 'hello' or 'Hello' must be converted to 'HEllo'.

Comment: Whatever answer you choose, make sure you check that your string is at least two characters long!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$txt = strtoupper( substr( $txt, 0, 2 ) ).substr( $txt, 2 );
```

This works also for strings that are less than 2 characters long.

Comment: Sometimes the simple and obvious solutions are best.

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = "hello";
$string{0} = strtoupper($string{0});
$string{1} = strtoupper($string{1});

var_dump($string);

//output: string(5) "HEllo"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's just a single word you need to do:

```
$ucfirsttwo = strtoupper(substr($word, 0, 2)) . substr($word, 2);
```

Basically, extract the first two characters and uppercase the, then attach the remaining characters.

If you need to handle multiple words in the string, then it gets a bit uglier.

Oh, and if you're using multi-byte characters, prefix the two functions with mb_ to get a multibyte-aware version.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = substr_replace($str, strtoupper($str[0].$str[1]), 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with the [`e` pattern modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) could be interesting here:

```
$str = 'HELLO';
echo preg_replace('/^(\w{1,2})/e', 'strtoupper(\\1)', strtolower($str));
```

EDIT:  It is recommended that you **not** use this approach.  From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers):

> Use of this modifier is discouraged, as it can easily introduce security vulnerabilites:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $html = $_POST['html'];
>
> // uppercase headings
> $html = preg_replace(
>     '(<h([1-6])>(.*?)</h\1>)e',
>     '"<h$1>" . strtoupper("$2") . "</h$1>"',
>     $html
> );
> ```
>
> The above example code can be easily exploited by passing in a string
>   such as `<h1>{${eval($_GET[php_code])}}</h1>`. This gives the attacker
>   the ability to execute arbitrary PHP code and as such gives him nearly
>   complete access to your server.
>
> To prevent this kind of remote code execution vulnerability the
>   preg_replace_callback() function should be used instead:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $html = $_POST['html'];
>
> // uppercase headings
> $html = preg_replace_callback(
>     '(<h([1-6])>(.*?)</h\1>)',
>     function ($m) {
>         return "<h$m[1]>" . strtoupper($m[2]) . "</h$m[1]>";
>     },
>     $html
> );
> ```

As recommended, instead of using the `e` pattern, consider using `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$str = 'HELLO';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(\w{1,2})/'
  , function( $m )
    {
      return strtoupper($m[1]);
    }
  , strtolower($str)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ucfirst`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) does only the first, but [substr access on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) works, too:

```
$str = ucfirst($str);
$str[1] = strtoupper($str[1]);
```

*Remark:* This works, but you will get notices on smaller strings if offset 1 is not defined, so not that safe, empty strings will even be converted to array. So it's merely to show some options.

Answer (score 1):

This should work `strtoupper(substr($target, 0, 2)) . substr($target, 2)` where $target is your 'hello' or whatever.